# Redis PUB/SUB and high availability

Tags: redis, high-availability

Currently I'm working on a distributed test execution and reporting system. I'm planning to use Redis PUB/SUB as a message queue and message distribution system.

I'm new to Redis, so I'm trying to read as many docs as I can and play around with it. One of the most important topics is high availability. As I said, I'm not an expert, but I'm aware of the possible options - using Sentinel, replication, clustering, etc.

What's not clear for me is how the Pub/Sub feature and the HA options are related each other. What's the best practice to build a reliable messaging system with Redis? By reliable I mean if my Redis message broker is down there should be some kind of a backup node (a slave?) that should be able to take over this role.

Is there a purely server-side solution? Or do I need to create a smart wrapper around the Redis client to handle this? Will a Sentinel-driven setup help me?

Comment: Haven't used pubsub in a distributed setup, but I think of redis as a data server first. Pubsub is a cherry on top. If you must have a reliable distributed message queue, there are specialized solutions. I heard RabbitMQ is pretty good.

Comment: Yep, we started to use Redis that way (as a "shared dictionary") - but while our project was shaping up, it turned out that message-based communication could be a better fit for our needs. Redis was there, and it supports it, so we started to use it as a message broker.
Nothing is carved to stone though, we'll check other solutions as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing pub sub in Redis with failover means thinking about additional factors in the client side. A key piece to understand is that subscriptions are per-connection. If you are subscribed to a channel on a node and it fails, you will need to handle reconnect and resubscribe. Because subscriptions are done at the connection level it is not something which can be replicated.

Regarding the details as to how it works and what you can expect to see, along with ways around it see a post I made earlier this year at https://objectrocket.com/blog/how-to/reliable-pubsub-and-blocking-commands-during-redis-failovers

You can lower the risk surface by subscribing to slaves and publishing to the master, but you would then need to have non-promotable slaves to subscribe to and still need to handle losing a slave - there is just as much chance to lose a given slave as there is a master.

Comment: Thanks, it made the picture lot more clear. Your blogpost is not as easy read for a redis-newbie, but definitely telling.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, PUB/SUB is not a good choice, may be [disque](https://github.com/antirez/disque) (comes from antirez, author of the Redis) fits better:

> Disque, an in-memory, distributed job queue

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it.